# mysql select with a LIMIT by field value

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql: Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

I tried `group by`, but then I'll only get 1 per account_id, I want 10 per account_id. Here's what I'm looking for.

```
SELECT id,account_id FROM whatever {LIMIT to 10 of each account_id}
```

Comment: I don't think I can use variables with my mysql driver

Comment: Who marked this as duplacate and provided that link? Don't you see that is absolutely different issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use rank for each account_id, id group

Example:

```
SELECT id,account_id FROM (
SELECT id,account_id,
   @acrank:=CASE 
               WHEN @aid <> id THEN 1 
               ELSE @acrank+1 END AS rn,
   @id:=id AS id_set
FROM
  (SELECT @acrank:= -1) nr,
  (SELECT @id:= -1) n,
  (SELECT * FROM Test ORDER BY id, account_id) t
  ) x WHERE rn < 11
```